# is there any references about mfc ui redraw... mechanism?

Tags: mfc

please give me some reference about the ui rendering mechanism
thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MFC is merely a thin wrapper around the Win32 API. It provides an object oriented foundation that simplifies the use of the C style Win32 API, but it doesn't have too much brains built into it. If you want to understand the way MFC creates UI, go a bit further and take a look at [GDI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145203(VS.85).aspx), which is the API used for UI stuff in Windows.